# Timer for an input in tigerjython?

Tags: python, python-3.x

, im trying to make a little quiz in tigerjython that should have a timer for each question making it fail once X seconds have passed.
From what ive seen and tested the code gets sort of "paused" until an input is done.
Im lacking a way to display the timer outside the console aswell

The timer itself for now is Just a small for loop that goes down by 1 every second

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried. You can [edit] your question at any time.